# SMTP authentication error on send mail, in a legacy code

Tags: c#, .net, email, .net-core, smtp

I'm experiencing a weird problem, as the title says whenever I try to send a mail, the following exception is thrown:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at'

Nothing out of the ordinary, however this is a code that was written about 2 years ago and hasn't been touched since, today when I ran it - suddenly doesn't work.

```
public static Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var client = BuildClient())
        {
            var message = BuildMessage(email, subject, htmlMessage);
            client.Send(message);
        }
    });
}

private static SmtpClient BuildClient()
{
    var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        EnableSsl = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx@abv.bg", "xxx")
    };

    return smtp;
}

private static MailMessage BuildMessage(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress("xxxx@abv.com"),
        Subject = subject,
        Body = htmlMessage
    };
    mailMessage.To.Add(email);

    return mailMessage;
}
```

As you can see the host is gmail.com, but I'm using a different email provider abv.bg, I've also tried swapping that with a gmail account, but the error is still the same.

This is a somewhat shortened version of the original code, but this also produces the error, since im not using gmail, there is no such a thing as "**Less secure apps**", or 2fa, this cant be the cause and even if it was when I attempted to use a gmail account, I enabled the less secure apps option, to no avail. I've ran this code under both .net core 3.0 and .net framework 4.7.2, same results. I'm also running this completely locally, so time zones shouldn't be a problem. And I've tripled, quadrupled checked the password and email.

So I'm basically clueless to why this is happening, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: if you moved off gmail as a mail provider why would you send them your email, surely your new provider has an smtp server

Comment: @BugFinder they do have one, but the client doesn't seem to be able to connect to it,it just times out.

Comment: then thats the actual thing you need to fix.  Chances are you have a firewall blocking it somewhere

Comment: Added rules for the the port of their smtp, now it just takes longer to timeout. @BugFinder

Comment: its not the code, its the networking - and thats well outside the scope of SO

Comment: There was a change in the Net library going from Net 3.5 to Net 4.0.  Net 3.5 did not require any credentials for SMTP.  Starting in Net 4.0 you have to set the credentials.  Port 587 is a secure port number for SMTP.  You have to check with the gmail home page which indicates the proper settings for using SMTP.  The requirements at gmail may have changed  Also the FROM address and the credentials have same gmail account.  You can also get exceptions if you exceed the gmail limits like the number of email per day or the number of email in the send box.